# find and delete zero Byte file in HDFS

Tags: shell, hadoop

I need to write a bash script that will help me locate and delete all zero byte files in hdfs .

I tried using this command

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R / | awk '$1 !~ /^d/ && $5 == "0" { print $8 }' | xargs -n100 hdfs dfs -rm
```

However, it doesn't locate all the files.

Is there a better way of achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
for f in $(hdfs dfs -ls -R / | awk '$1 !~ /^d/ && $5 == "0" { print $8 }'); do hdfs dfs -rm "$f"; done
```